# How to use task factory with my existing code in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code to send out SMSes to mobile phones using C# with ASP.NET. But since its the lengthy process, the UI is stuck until the process is finish.

So I was thinking to separate the process from the UI thread. I'm still a learner so I did some research and found out that I could archive what I want with TaskFactory from .Net Framework 4.

But I still don't quite understand the usage of TaskFactory.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //Gets Subscriber number
    smsSender.destinationNum = Convert.ToInt64(row["callerID"]);
    foreach (DataRow articleRow in dtArticle.Rows)
    {
        //Gets SMS content
        smsSender.smsMessage = articleRow["news"].ToString();
        //Then send out the SMS
        smsSendder.sendSMS();
    }
}
```

The above piece of code sends out the SMSes. I wrote it in the button click event. What I would like to archive is -

1. Separate the process from UI so that user doesn't have to wait. (Use can navigate to other pages too)
2. Check the status of the task.
3. Cancel the task if its necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a bit of reading to understand the usage. If someone just posts the running code, you'll not really understand nor learning it.

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism

http://www.albahari.com/threading